# CMake importing both shared and static library versions, but I only want one

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, antlr

I would like to use the Antlr framework in a project. I'm using CMake to build the project.

I would like to use the SHARED library version of Antlr, not the STATIC one. Its CMake file contains targets for both.

Antlr's github site explicity tells me to use the following code:

```
find_package(antlr4-runtime REQUIRED)

# add runtime include directories on this project.
include_directories( ${ANTLR4_INCLUDE_DIR} )

# add runtime to project dependencies
add_dependencies( Parsertest antlr4_shared )

# add runtime to project link libraries
target_link_libraries( Parsertest PRIVATE
                       antlr4_shared)
```

(another target, `antlr4_static`, exists, but shouldn´t be used.)

I copied it exactly like this and am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/cmake/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-targets.cmake:82 (message):
  The imported target "antlr4_static" references the file

     "/usr/lib/libantlr4-runtime.a"

  but this file does not exist.
```

I dont have the static library installed in my system as I have no intention of using it. Still, how do I make CMake stop looking for the wrong target in the first place? I use it nowhere in my CMakeLists.txt file and am puzzled by this behavior.

Comment: You can find a full bloat sample using ANTLR with CMake on GitHub https://github.com/eclipse/che-che4z-lsp-for-hlasm so try to play with its code base and learn what you missed.